# How to give option to user for choosing the file folder in xamarin forms?

Tags: file, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to give user an ability to chose the desired **file location** in his/her device to save information.
I didn't find anything on the Internet that would work for all the platforms. The only options seem to be available for Android.

Comment: Could you elaborate, is this regarding map locations?

Comment: Could you elaborate better your question sir? I really didn't understand your problem.

You would like to create a fake GPS ?

Comment: Not gps location, file location, i want to give user access to choose where he wants to save a file or frome where he wants to load the file.

Comment: Hey,is my answer helpful?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the package `Xamarin.Plugin.FilePicker` from NuGet. It is a FilePicker Plugin for Xamarin.Forms.

**Example:**

```
try
{
   FileData fileData = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile();
   if (fileData == null)
       return; // user canceled file picking

   string fileName = fileData.FileName;
   string contents = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fileData.DataArray);

   System.Console.WriteLine("File name chosen: " + fileName);
   System.Console.WriteLine("File data: " + contents);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   System.Console.WriteLine("Exception choosing file: " + ex.ToString());
}
```

For iOS ,you need to  [Configure iCloud Driver for your app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/data-cloud/intro-to-cloudkit).For more detail and if you want download a sample you can refer [here](https://github.com/jfversluis/FilePicker-Plugin-for-Xamarin-and-Windows).

Answer (score 0):

For IOS you can read this document.

https://possiblemobile.com/2013/04/using-xcode-to-test-location-services/

All,( android and IOS ) can be manipulated by **dependency injection**. So you are using native code of android and of IOS and choose/control in xamarin forms.

Good luck

Guilherme